# Not installing and running datawarrior550.tar_gz please help i want to run the program

Tags: display

```
file id tar_gz 
of datawarrior550 not unzipped with terminal command

unknown suffix  --ignored
ngs@NU-NGS:~/Downloads$ gunzip datawarrior550.tar_gz
gzip: datawarrior550.tar_gz: unknown suffix -- ignored
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to rename this file to match its filetype.

For your case it should be `datawarrior550.tar.gz` and not `datawarrior550.tar_gz`. The `gunzip` application expects dot between `tar` and `gz`.

Also there is better one shot way - use `tar` command as follows:

```
tar -xf datawarrior550.tar.gz
```

---

Man-pages to read:

- `man gunzip` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/gunzip.1.html)
- `man tar` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/tar.1.html)